# Как запретить просмотр файлов .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
Какой параметр .htaccess запрещает просмотр файлов папки?
Чтобы пользователи не могли попасть в папку и файл был недоступен для них?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order deny allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```